# Turning pattern to code using if statement and condition

Tags: c, if-statement

I need to turn this pattern into a condition for an If statement. Could anyone help me that would be great thanks. The pattern is attached in the image below. It doesn't need to print anything I just wondering how I could write a statement for it.

[Pattern Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHPHk.jpg)

Comment: Tip: Two for-loops and the % operator would help

Comment: You should clearly communicate what you are asking instead of just linking some image: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.